# How to unregister TdxPNGImage as a property handler?

Tags: devexpress, png, delphi-xe2

I am using Delphi XE2. I have Dev Express 12 installed and use it for some projects.

However I have projects where I do not use DevExpress at all, and I wanted for those to not have any dependency on it.

When I assign a PNG image to any TPicture property on Object Inspector it always use a TdxPNGImage class to handle it.

That cause to add the unit dxGDIPlusClasses creating dependency on having DevExpress installed.

But I need to not break DevExpress on my Delphi. It must continue to work for those projects based on it and that eventually will need this png class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I have missed the answer of this on DevExpress forum, even after many searches.

I am posting here the link for the issue and possible solutions:

[Delphi 2010 always uses the TdxPNGImage class for loading PNG images (this corrupts form streaming)](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/B143725)

I have tested and it works.